# How to prevent dispatch action to re-render screen - redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I use redux to dispatch an action it's a trigger 'true/false',

So i have a bottom sheet modal contain 'mini-player' when i open it grow height modal to contain the player controller.

in the player controller when i press to a 'play/pause icon' i dispatch an action to set pause from false to true or opposite

but the problem is when action dispatching it's back modal to the bassed height "mini-player"

Gif
[image: gif here]

So how can i solve it?

in other words, prevent re-render the modal?

Code

Player controller

```
<View>

 <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 10}}>
   <Video
     ....
       paused={this.props.isPause} // redux store
      ....
   />

 </View>

  {!this.props.isPause ? (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.isPauseTrigger(true)}> // redux action
          <Icon name="md-pause" style={styles.iconColor} />
      </Button>
       ) : (
          <Button
             onPress={() => this.props.isPauseTrigger(false)}> // redux action
               <Icon name="md-play" style={styles.iconColor} />
          </Button>
  )}
 </View>
```

Mini-Player Component I used 'react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet'

```
const renderHeader = () => {
    const animatedBackgroundOpacity = Animated.sub(
      1,
      animatedHeaderContentOpacity,
    );
    return (
      <View onPress={onHeaderPress} key={'header-container'}>

          <Animated.View
            intensity={100}
            tint={'default'}
            style={[
              styles.headerContentContainer,
              {
                opacity: animatedHeaderContentOpacity,
              },
            ]}>               

            <View>
             ....
              {props.isPause ? ( // Redux State
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    props.isPauseTrigger(false); // Redux action
                    console.log('should play?', props.isPause);
                  }}
                  style={styles.headerActionButton}>
                  <Ionicons color="#282A36" name="ios-play" size={30} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    props.isPauseTrigger(true); // Redux action
                    console.log('should pause?', props.isPause);
                  }}
                  style={styles.headerActionButton}>
                  <Ionicons color="#282A36" name="ios-pause" size={30} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>

          </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  };




 const renderContent = () => {
       return (
        <Player />
    );
  };
```

**What I tried**

When i change paused property in `<Video />` to use local state 'inside controller player component', It works well without any issue like in GIF **But** I want to change the icon when i minimize the bottom player.

so it's not listening to the redux state because I use local state

Answer (score 0):

React Re-renders components based on changes in props or states. You can use *componentShouldUpdate* lifecycle method to prevent default behavior.
Based on how you handle mini-player open/closed state there could be other solutions as well.

Comment: Hmm, I could not understand you well, should I use componentShouldUpdate in which component?

Comment: @OliverD In component which you handle mini-player being open or closed state.

Comment: The bottom mini-player it's apparently based on another state and it's open by swiping "react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet" so I think the issues with the icon in mini-player because I change icon based on isPause state redux and onPress use the same 'isPasueTrigger()'? What you think?

Comment: When i change paused property <Video /> to local state 'inside controller component', It's work well without any issue like in GIF but the I want to change the icon when i minimize the bottom player so it's not listening to the redux state cuz i use local state !

Comment: @OliverD Could be that. I can't guess till I didn't see the code.

Comment: I add a mini-player Code can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

What is your parent component?
How are you controling the open/close of the modal and if it works with state and all you need is the butto n icon play/pause you can lift the state, i.e you dont need to store in redux.

So on parent:
State: player: "playing"

Func updatePlayer(mode) this.setState(player:mode)

And in your modal comp wherever you are done with it and have a func to closeModal() just have this.props.updatePlayer(this.state.playerState)
Which will update state on the parent.